# Conformal Coupling for QFT in Curved Spacetime

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-gravity

I have seen it stated but not explained that consistency requires you to couple massless fields to gravity using the conformal coupling, so that $trT_{\mu \nu}=0$. What is the reason for this?

Comment: As far as I know, *just referring to the general formulation of QFT in curved spacetime*, there is **no** such requirement. Indeed, generally speaking the coupling parameter, usually indicated by $\xi$ has a generic value in the term $\xi \phi^2 R$ of the Lagrangian density of a scalar field $\phi$. $R$ is the scalar curvature. For a massless scalar the conformal coupling corresponds to $\xi=1/6$ in four dimensions. (Actually after quantization, a conformal anomaly arises depending on curvatures)

Comment: I have never seen such an assertion, either be it in textbooks such as Birrell&Davies, or in the inumerous papers that appear working with non-conformal coupling. Could you give a reference for this statement?

Comment: http://ac.els-cdn.com/0003491670903945/1-s2.0-0003491670903945-main.pdf?_tid=84b58a5e-df9a-11e3-8560-00000aab0f6b&acdnat=1400534229_29a5eea0d3410058c46f5858822a22f2 Is one of the places I remember seeing the idea. If I remember correctly they want the conformal coupling so that T has finite matrix elements. Any comment?

Comment: Penrose mentions the necessity of this in a paper "conformal treatment of infinity" It seems that if you want your lagrangian to be conformally invariant you need such a term (If I remember correctly)